# nmake.exe is not found in the windows\system32 folder? how to setup nmake command in windows?

Tags: nmake

When I type the `nmake` command in the Command Prompt, I am getting this error:

> 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

Also, I couldn't find the `nmake.exe` file in my system.

**How to setup the `nmake` command on Windows?**

Answer (score 7):

NMake is part of Microsoft's build tools for building C++ projects. You can get nmake as well as the MSVC++ compiler by downloading [Visual C++ Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs#2010-Visual-CPP). Visual C++ Express which runs perfectly fine on *Windows 7*.
 It will install nmake.exe to 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin`
 on Windows 7 without prompting for an alternate directory. As this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/146577/where-do-i-find-nmake-for-windows-7-x64) answered

Comment: So for Installing Visual C++ Express my system should have Visual studio or Windows SDK.  am I correct?

Comment: C++ Express should include everything you need for nmake because nmake is included with the MS build tools (packaged in Visual studio) from my understanding

Comment: OR it looks like you have the option to just install the SDK which should also include it

Comment: I have the nmake.exe in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\ path but I am not able to run the nmake command in the command prompt

Comment: You'll need to run it from a command shell that was packaged with VS. Go to your start menu --> all programs --> Microsoft Visual Studio [your year] --> Visual studio tools --> then run any of the three command prompts. Good luck! P.S. if this answered your question make sure to mark it as correct, let me know if you have anymore trouble

Comment: While running the nmake command ."fatal error U1064 MAKEFILE not found and not target specified Stop" is shown

Comment: Glad to hear it, does everything seem to be working okay now?