# argon2 elixir compilation issue while mix ecto.create

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am getting the below error while running `mix ecto.create` to create the postgres DB.

```
==> argon2_elixir
could not compile dependency :argon2_elixir, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile argon2_elixir", update it with "mix deps.update argon2_elixir" or clean it with "mix deps.clean argon2_elixir"
==> snitch_core
** (Mix) "nmake" not found in the path. If you have set the MAKE environment variable,
please make sure it is correct.
```

I am defining it in the `mix.exs` file under `apps` folder as below:

```
  # auth
  {:elixir_make, "~> 0.4.2"},
  {:comeonin, "~> 4.1.1"},
  {:argon2_elixir, "~> 1.3.3"},
```

Tried to recompile the package as suggested in the error message but nothing helped.

Appreciate help in this regard.

Comment: Check if ˋnmakeˋ is on your path. If not, add it or define the ˋMAKEˋ environment variable prperly.

Comment: I checked - it is already added in the PATH in env variable. PATH is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx64\x64\nmake.exe

Comment: It doesn't matter if nmake is in the path or not if you don't have the environment variables (e. g. %INCLUDE%) defined correctly.  nmake uses those environment variables to find files it needs. Given what turns out to be the answer below, I'd say you should simply build a .cmd file that sets these variables before attempting to run mix.

Comment: Found any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you don't have `nmake` installed. You're on Windows I presume? Install `nmake` one way or another, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35507773/409792).

Comment: `nmake` is installed. I even ran the `nmake.exe /F MAKEFILE` command in Visual Studio command shell without any issues. Yes I am in WIN 10.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it finally. Here is the general approach to attack the problem and solve it, irrespective of your specific issues.

First, I copied the `nmake.exe` from the visual studio folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx64\x64\` and pasted in System32 folder. Ran the command `mix ecto.create` and received a changed elaborate error which solved the issue. Here is the output of the error:
`** (Mix) Could not compile with "nmake" (exit status: 2).
One option is to install a recent version of
[Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)
either manually or using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) -`
choco install VisualCppBuildTools`.

After installing Visual C++ Build Tools, look in the "Program Files (x86)"
directory and search for "Microsoft Visual Studio". Note down the full path
of the folder with the highest version number. Open the "run" command and
type in the following command (make sure that the path and version number
are correct):

```
cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

This should open up a command prompt with the necessary environment variables
set, and from which you will be able to run the "mix compile", "mix deps.compile",
and "mix test" commands.`

Follow this line by line, and success is at your feet. :)