# Getting error whent trying build project via CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying build project via CMake, few days earlier this process worked fine, but today I am getting error after command  `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..` :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   The system cannot find the specified file 


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am using Visual Studio Code,  name of project folder is "ADC_read", and my CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
# Set minimum required version of CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# Include build functions from Pico SDK
include($ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH}/external/pico_sdk_import.cmake)

# Set name of project (as PROJECT_NAME) and C/C   standards
project(ADC_read C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Creates a pico-sdk subdirectory in our project for the libraries
pico_sdk_init()

# Tell CMake where to find the executable source file
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    main.c
)

# Create map/bin/hex/uf2 files
pico_add_extra_outputs(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Link to pico_stdlib (gpio, time, etc. functions)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    pico_stdlib adc_read hardware_adc
)


# Enable usb output, disable uart output
pico_enable_stdio_usb(${PROJECT_NAME} 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(${PROJECT_NAME} 0)
```

Anyone know where could be problem?

==========================% EDIT %===============================
Semisolved...

So I am still not able to build project from **Visual Studio Code** (VSC can´t find  `nmake`),  but building from **VS command prompt** works fine, so I will stick with this.

Comment: By specifying option `-G "NMake Makefiles"` you tell CMake that you want to build your project via `nmake`. But the error message tells that you don't have `nmake` installed. If you want to build the project with Visual Studio, then select proper generator from that list: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators

Comment: @TsyvarevI I thought nmake was part of Visual Studio, so how it's possible I don't have nmake installed??

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok so I have another maybe stupid question. I didn't find how to install `nmake`, is then `nmake` part of CMake (which I have installed)?

Comment: Hm, I was not very correct in my previous comment: `nmake` is (in some extent) a part of Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507646/nmake-exe-is-not-found-in-the-windows-system32-folder-how-to-setup-nmake-comman. But do you **actually** have Visual Studio installed? Note, that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are very different things.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, I have installed Visual Studio 2019. And as I writted in question, command `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"` worked fine few days before and I did make no changes since that.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `CMakeCache.txt` file, as it holds your previous generator data.
You can then recompile your project with cmake and it should work !